mypy Cannot infer type argument. Difference between List and Iterable
T = TypeVar("T", bound=Union[str, int])


def connect_lists(list_1: list[T], list_2: list[T]) -> list[T]:
    out: list[T] = []
    out.extend(list_1)
    out.extend(list_2)
    return out

connect_lists([1, 2], ["a", "b"])

mypy:

error: Cannot infer type argument 1 of "connect_lists"  [misc]

T = TypeVar("T", bound=Union[str, int])


def connect_lists(list_1: Iterable[T], list_2: Iterable[T]) -> list[T]:
    out: list[T] = []
    out.extend(list_1)
    out.extend(list_2)
    return out

connect_lists([1, 2], ["a", "b"])

Now mypy doesn't raise an error.
What is the difference between List and Iterable in this case?

I would have expected both to produce an error, honestly. In previous versions of mypy (before 1.7), both examples produce an error. The fact that the second example works may be a bug.

@sytech hmmm, why would you expect both to produce an error? pyright handles both cases fine, and infers list[int | str] in both cases.

Use Iterable or Sequence which are covariant whenever possible. list is invariant (list[int] is not a subtype of list[int | str] because of mutability). In this case mypy could have done better, but apparently stopped at inferring argument types of list[int] and list[str], failing to promote both to list[int | str], and then obviously failed to solve T. https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=5b5334511e3eddb1e418b98f1adc3820

@sytech no, it's not how type vars work. They are not restricted to first argument - all restrictions are solved together. You can imagine it as some kind of a system of equations. Assuming def foo(a: T, b: T) -> None: pass, foo('a', 10) is a valid call, with T solved to int | str. Aren't you confusing TypeVar('T', bound=int|str) with TypeVar('T', int, str)?

@STerliakov you're right, I was mistaken.

I'm going to be honest: type variables bound to unions make my head hurt

For whatever it's worth, this change appears to be what is responsible for the second case to pass checks since mypy 1.7 -- but I'm still clueless as to why that works for Iterable[T] but not list[T]. I tested by removing the code that calls pre_validate_solutions and found that it causes the second case to fail again. Hope that helps someone with bigger brains than myself to figure out the root cause of this.

Iterable is covariant - an Iterable[int] is also an Iterable[int|str].
list is not covariant - a list[int] is not a list[int|str], because you can add strings to a list[int|str], which you can't do with a list[int].
mypy infers the types of [1, 2] and ["a", "b"] as list[int] and list[str] respectively. With the first definition of connect_objects, there is no choice of T that will make the call valid. But with the second definition, a list[int] is an Iterable[int], which is an Iterable[int|str], and a list[str] is similarly also an Iterable[int|str], so T is inferred as int|str.
I don't think there's actually a spec yet for how type inference works. There may never be such a spec. Future mypy versions might perform this inference differently, for example, performing context-sensitive inference to infer a type of list[int|str] for both input lists, making the first version of the code pass type checking.
